# Limit Airflow DAG Visibility By AD/LDAP Groups

Tags: airflow

Is is possible to limit visibility and accessibility of DAGs by user groups in Airflow?

For example, I want to have one large Airflow environment for my entire company, different teams will be using this Airflow environment for their team's workflows. Say we have team A and team B who both belong to their respective AD/LDAP groups, group A and group B. Is it possible to have group A only see the DAGs that belong to their team and vice versa with group B?

Based on my research and understanding I don't think this will be possible on a single Airflow environment. I think in order for me to do this I will need to create a separate Airflow environment for each team so that each team will have their own Airflow Dags folder containing their respective DAGs.

Comment: i.e., no relevant articles were found that describe how to limit visibility of DAGs by groups.

Comment: In 1.10.2 they added DAG-level access controls. As far as I can tell, you still have to manually map DAG's to a role. You also have to manually assign users to a role; a role can't be backed by an LDAP group. https://github.com/minio/cookbook/blob/master/docs/how-to-use-minio-server-side-encryption-with-aws-cli.md

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think there are two different problems posed here:

First, LDAP authentication.  Airflow provides [support for LDAP authentication](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#ldap) built on [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/).  The example in the linked doc shows how to associate Airflow roles with LDAP groups (e.g., the `data_profiler_filter` part).

Second, restricting DAG access by group.  As of the time of this writing, the current version of Airflow (1.9), doesn't support limiting visibility of DAGs by group.  The recent work on role-based access control (RBAC) changes this.  I've listed 3 different options for addressing this problem below.

---

### Option 1 - RBAC (most control, available in Airflow ≥ 1.10)

The new RBAC features add support for permissions like this and is the best for fine-grained control.  It uses a permission system built on Flask App Builder.  This was created by a company with a very similar use case to what you mentioned which is discussed in more detail in the Jira issue.

More info can be found in:

- [RBAC proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Airflow+RBAC+proposal)
- [AIRFLOW-85 - Create DAGs UI](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-85)
- [PR #3015](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3015)

The RBAC webserver UI is available on master now in [airflow/www_rbac](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/www_rbac).  Other features around RBAC are also being actively developed to further improve security in a multi-tenancy setup.

Note: There's also ongoing work on a new DAG-level access control (DLAC) feature in [AIRFLOW-2267](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2267) which builds upon the RBAC work to introduce even more fine-grained control.  More info can be found in the [design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qs26lE9kAuCY0Qa0ga-80EQ7d7m4s-590lhjtMBjmxw/edit?usp=sharing) and [PR #3197](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3197).

---

### Option 2 - Multi-tenancy with owners (simplest, available in Airflow < 1.10)

A second option you can consider for medium-grained control is a [multi-tenancy setup](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#multi-tenancy) using `webserver.filter_by_owner` and setting one explicit `owner` (a user, not a group) for each DAG. "With this, a user will see only the dags which it is owner of, unless it is a superuser."

*Aside: A related feature you might be interested in running tasks as a specific user with [impersonation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#impersonation) using `run_as_user` or `core.default_impersonation`.*

---

### Option 3 - Run multiple separate Airflow instances (highest isolation)

A third option for coarse-grained control that some companies choose is to run multiple separate Airflow instances, one per team.  This is probably the most practical for those looking to run multiple teams' DAGs in isolation today.  If you happen to use [Astronomer Enterprise](https://www.astronomer.io/enterprise/), we support spinning up multiple Airflow instances.

Comment: I think RBAC only available since 2.0?

Comment: @Charmy Once 2.0 is released, I believe the RBAC UI will become the default with the old UI being deprecated.  As of 1.10 though, RBAC is available and many people already use it.  You can find more info on how to enable and use it at [RBAC UI Security](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#rbac-ui-security).  You can also find more info around RBAC feature releases in the [Airflow Changelog](https://airflow.apache.org/changelog.html).

Comment: Option 2, filter_by_owner. Doesn't work. It is true that users who do not own the DAG cannot see it on the DAGs screen, but once the owner (or another process) triggers the DAG, any user can access the DAG main screen from "Browse > DAG Runs" and delete/modify/trigger it.

Comment: @amza Thank you.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.  If you're using < 1.10, I think you may have identified a bug.  If you're using ≥ 1.10, it looks like this option was deprecated with the introduction of RBAC. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blame/201e67100c200d38dbc3cd530cd04dd31bf91d7f/UPDATING.md#L142-L150

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston I didn't see your updated answer mentioning that. I only realized this concern upon reading amza's comment

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have an array of owners another option would be

1. Define a variable with your group as an array of usernames in json

```
// Variable: group-datascience
["dinigo","michael","david"]
```

2. In your new dag set this config as the owner

```py
dag = DAG(
  dag_id='dag-with-group-scope',
  owner= Variable.get('group-datascience', parse_json=True),
  # some more config
)
```

3. Activate the owner filtering in the airflow.cfg or via environment variable
4. Remove variables viewing/editing permission to those people with a custom role. Otherwise they could modify it whenever they want

This is only makeup and it's highly hackable. Since anyone can query all the variables from a task (can they?). But it can help organize